# How to retrieve nodes for multiple depth relationships Neo4j Database Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Assuming that there is a simple graph as follows,

```
(City {name:gotham})<-[:LOCATED]-(Tower {name:abc})<-[:LOCATED]-(Bank:{name:CityBank})
(City {name:gotham})<-[:LOCATED]-(Cinema {name:MainHall})
(City {name:gotham})<-[:LOCATED]-(Bank {name:ComBank})
```

How can i get all banks located in City named Gotham in Neo4j Database (including CityBank and comBank)? I tried following pattern, it returned all the nodes LOCATED in City named gotham (Including Cinema as well)

```
MATCH (City{name:'Gotham'})<--(Bank) RETURN Bank
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Assuming you just mistyped the query, what isn't working?</strike>

```
MATCH (:City{name:'Gotham'})<--(bank:Bank) RETURN bank
```

should work fine.

Completely wrong as typed, should have read (the lonely star indicating, all relationships of any type, any length path):

```
MATCH (:City{name:'Gotham'})<-[*]-(bank:Bank) RETURN bank
```

Better would be:

```
MATCH (:City{name:'Gotham'})<-[:LOCATED*1..2]-(bank:Bank) RETURN bank
```

So as only to traverse `LOCATED` relationships. You can adjust the `*1..2` (match paths of length 1 to 2) to meet path length requirements (if for example you added a Street or Block node, you might want to match paths up to length 3 `*1..3`)

Comment: First query only returns ComBank but not CityBank i checked that. Second query is the one i was expecting, i can use it like this [LOCATED*] without specified depths